# How to convert byte array to multipart file using angular 10?

Tags: angular, byte, multipartfile

I have a requirement to convert byte[] to Multipart using Angular 10.
How can I do this?

In receiving email I get the image as byte[] I want to convert this to Multipart file and send.
How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Assuming you have a byte[] called myBytes
const myBlob = new Blob([myBytes]);
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', myBlob, 'filename.bin');

const req = new HttpRequest('POST', ' upload url ', formData, {
  reportProgress: true
});

// You can then use the HttpClient to send the request
this.http.request(req).subscribe(event => {
  // Handle response
});
```

Comment: How to pass the file content type?

Comment: try 
formData.append('file', myBlob, 'filename.bin', { type: 'application/octet-stream' });